# Word, or phrase for... two organisms that come together, grow -- but their mutual product harms their locality, and they benefit from that too?

Tags: american-english

two organisms that *come together*, **grow** -- but their *mutual product* **harms** their *locality*, and **they benefit** from that too?

Comment: Can you give an example of such a pair?

Comment: The collocation ***symbiotic cancer*** comes to mind. But much depends on how one defines ***harms** their locality* - obviously from the perspective of these organisms (who *benefit* from changes they cause in their environment), they're not harming anything at all. Unless they're so dumb they end up killing their host without making provision for their future survival - but evolution would quickly screen them out anyway.

Comment: I am writing a paper, writing my thesis, my idea is a complex metaphor using intensely accurate similes.  another metaphor for what I am trying to say is,      has evolved into a fascist machine

 fed by the private sector in order to sustain an adequate profit margin and product growth.

Comment: new user learning the system, didnt know enter, entered...

Comment: fascist machine fed by the private sector

Comment: fascist - goverment / machine - FDA for my paper / private sector - private sector

Comment: If it's a "machine" why are you searching for terms relating to organisms? That doesn't seem "intensely accurate" to me, as similes and metaphors go.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you are entirely right.  So, would this sound correct.

Comment: "Mutually invasive cancers whose noxiousity only propels them in size."

Comment: @TRomano I am brainstorming on my thesis, and that was my natural "quick" metaphor, realized that its not really accurate.  any ideas, all intellectual property aside?  hah

Comment: *Mutually invasive cancers* makes no sense. Cancers can't exist inside of each other. On the other hand, you could talk about a criminal partnership, where the individuals' crimes mutually benefit each other (to the detriment of the victims).

Comment: How would you word that @JasonBassford?  Invasively mutual cancers?  In context to which it applies.

Comment: wouldn't that be like a double negative, and turn it back into mutually invasive?  please, let the wisdom flood

Comment: What I'm saying is that the use of *mutual* with *cancer* (whether you add *invasive* or not, and in any order) doesn't make sense. In fact, one cancer can't *have* another cancer at all. Cancer exists only in otherwise healthy tissue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems hypothetical, however there are a few words that can describe this in biology. They are "**invasive**" (by implication) for one. they are "**mutualistic**" (also by implication) for another. And, lastly, both organisms are "**noxious**" (to native organisms) in their new host environment. I suppose such a pair of organisms would be considered an example of "**invasive noxious mutualism**" using biological terms.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/invasive

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/noxious

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mutualism

Comment: do you have an opinion/ fact on if their is a word or phrase to define 'noxiousness' produced from the mutually invasive, actually benefited the mutually invasive as well.  I keep thinking propulsion, propulsion, propulsion.  Kind of like exponential staging.

Comment: Private sector or government? Maybe both? Any particular administration in mind?